# Corona SQL pass row ID in tableView to new Scene

Tags: sql, lua, scrollview, tableview, coronasdk

I've found a similair question to my problem and so far its working for me, Im getting the row ID printed with a print statement.

I am displaying data from my Database in a tableView. With the onTouch function I want the data showed in a new Scene in a scrollView that gets that data specifically to that clicked row. So for example I am clikcing on the tableView on Capital_NL, it has to show Amsterdam in the scrollView (Scene 2).

This is my code so far:

Scene 1:

```lua
local count = 0
local baslikRow = {}

for row in db:nrows("SELECT dua_id, baslik FROM dua") do
    count = count + 1
    baslikRow[count] = {}
    baslikRow[count].baslik = row.baslik
    baslikRow[count].dua_id = row.dua_id
end

local function tableViewListener( event )
    print(event.phase)
end

local function onRowRender( event )

    local row = event.row

    local rowHeight = row.contentHeight
    local rowWidth = row.contentWidth

    local options = 
    {
        parent = row,
        text = baslikRow[row.index].baslik,
        x = 20,
        y = 0,
        font = native.systemFont,
        fontSize = 16
    }

    local rowTitle = display.newText(options)
    rowTitle:setFillColor( 0, 0, 0 )

    rowTitle.anchorX = 0
    rowTitle.x = 15
    rowTitle.y = rowHeight * 0.5
end

local function onRowTouch( event )     
    local row = event.row

    if event.phase == 'tap' then
        print("Pressed rowNR: " .. row.index )
        print("Pressed rowID: " .. event.target.params.paramID)
        composer.gotoScene("scene2")
    end
end

local tableView = widget.newTableView{
    left = 0,
    top = 0,
    height = display.contentHeight,
    width = display.contentWidth,
    onRowRender = onRowRender,
    onRowTouch = onRowTouch,
}

for i = 1, count do
    tableView:insertRow
    {
        rowHeight = 50,
        rowid = baslikRow[count].dua_id,
        params = { paramID = baslikRow[i].dua_id }
    }
end

sceneGroup:insert(tableView)
```

Scene 2:

```lua
---------------------
-- CREATE SCROLLVIEW
---------------------
local scrollView = widget.newScrollView
{
    left = 0,
    top = 0,
    width = display.contentWidth,
    height = display.contentHeight,
    topPadding = 0,
    bottomPadding = 0,
    horiontalScrollDisabled = true,
    verticalScrollDisable = false,
    listener = scrollListener,
}
sceneGroup:insert(scrollView)


---------------------
-- GET DATA FROM DB
---------------------
for row in db:nrows("SELECT metni FROM dua") do

    local rowParams = 
    {
        duaID       = row.dua_id,
        Metni       = row.metni,
    }

    local options =
    {
        text = row.metni,
        x = display.contentCenterX + 20,
        y = display.contentHeight / 2,
        width = 300,
        width = display.contentWidth,
        font = native.systemFontBold,   
        fontSize = 18,
    }

    local t = display.newText(options)
    t:setTextColor(0)
    scrollView:insert(t)
end
```

What I have right now is, whenever I click on, for example Capital_NL or Capital_USA or Capital_Germany, I always get the result Amsterdam back.

How do I pass the data thats in the same Row in the database from Scene 1 to Scene 2

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to display the (metni) data based on the row number tapped on the previuos scene ..

Try this inside scene1 ..

```
for row in db:nrows("SELECT dua_id, baslik, metni FROM dua") do
   count = count + 1
   baslikRow[count] = {}
   baslikRow[count].baslik = row.baslik
   baslikRow[count].dua_id = row.dua_id
   baslikRow[count].metni = row.metni
```

inside the onRowTouch event handler:

```
composer.gotoScene("scene2",{params = baslikRow[row.index].metni})
```

This way you can pass the data you want to use .. I guess you don't need to use the database code inside scene2 ..

to access the data passed from scene1 to scene2

```
local selectedRow = event.params
```

Then ..

```
local options =
    {
        text = selectedRow,
        x = display.contentCenterX + 20,
        y = display.contentHeight / 2,
        width = 300,
        width = display.contentWidth,
        font = native.systemFontBold,   
        fontSize = 50,
    }

    local t = display.newText(options)
    t:setTextColor(0)
    scrollView:insert(t)
```

I think thats what you asked for .. If NOT, please explain more and give us a screenshot of your "dua" table ..